# Mapped drive download/upload is really slow

Tags: azure-storage-files

I shared some files on azure storage.

My internet speed is 8Mbps but I am getting around 1Mbps when I download files from the shared drive.

Could you please let me know how I can increase bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

The Target throughput for single file share can up to 60MB per second in Azure File storage, We could find this information here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/. So I think this issue is not caused by Azure storage side. Different Azure VM size has different network bandwidth. Refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-sizes/ for more details. I would suggest you change the VM size to see whether it can improve your bandwidth. Finally, please check your environment network bandwidth, make sure no other Apps are occupied bandwidth.